# sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied on laravel mix

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I'm trying to run `npm run dev` but the following error occur:

```
sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shanmaseen/.npm/_logs/2019-02-22T16_32_08_191Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shanmaseen/.npm/_logs/2019-02-22T16_32_08_241Z-debug.log
```

I've been searching the internet for a week, nothing helped at all !

I even tried to remove 'cross-env' from package.json scripts, but then webpack: permission denied happened, indicating that the permission error is not by cross-env it self.

this is the error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.7.0
3 info using node@v11.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/media/e/www/mwar/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /media/e/www/mwar
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:984:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /media/e/www/mwar
16 verbose Linux 4.18.0-15-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v11.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

I'm using laravel 5.7mix.

node version: v11.10.0
npm version: 6.7.0

any help please?

Comment: See this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sh-1-cross-env-permission-denied

Comment: @Molda didn't work.
I even tried to install a fresh laravel project, but still didn't work.

Comment: The problem might be JS file permissions. 

I solved by adding to Homestead.yml folders section:
'
      type: "smb"
      mount_options: ["mfsymlinks,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0775"]

'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I figure out the problem, the storage where the project is saved is auto-mounted and it have no execution permission.

easily in /etc/fstab file i added `exec` in the mount option, like this:

```
auto,user,exec,utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw 0 0
```

Comment: Hey @shamaseen, would you mind to explain a bit on how to do this? I think I have the same issue. I am encountering this on Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant

Comment: @S.Domeng open /etc/fstab file and add `exec` like illustrated above

Answer (score 187):

I was on ubuntu 18.

Following command helped me :-)

```
npm rebuild
```

**Documented as follows, on the official website.**

This command runs the `npm build` command on the matched folders. This is useful when you install a new version of node, and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary. It is also useful when installing with `--ignore-scripts` and `--no-bin-links`, to explicitly choose which packages to build and/or link bins.

If one or more package names (and optionally version ranges) are provided, then only packages with a name and version matching one of the specifiers will be rebuilt.

Comment: where did you run this command? in project folder or anywhere? it did not work for me.

Comment: in the root of your project folder.

Comment: @Zarpio This solution works for me just now, runnng Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: worked on macOS ventura as well

Comment: Please properly source and cite any content that is not your own, or it may be [deleted as plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421874/why-was-my-answer-deleted-for-plagiarism-despite-mentioning-the-source?cb=1).

Answer (score 58):

This is because of permission issues with global installation of packages, which npm is being denied access.

To solve this try

1.

```
npm rebuild

npm run watch
```

Or 2

```
rm -Rf node_modules

npm install

npm run watch
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Making a user the owner of `/usr/local` is solving the issue through an anti pattern. This directory is supposed to _serve_ users by supplying read-only data for users. ([manual](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html))

Comment: @BasPeeters I have edited the solution. I have removed the anti-pattern point as per your recommendation, thank you.

Comment: method two works

Answer (score 57):

The following thing worked for me

```
chmod -R a+x node_modules
```

[source](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/error-sh-1-cross-env-permission-denied/)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me and was easy. Probably the best answer.

Comment: Thanks this works... you just need to make sure this runs after you run npm install (if you do)

Comment: You should not give execution rights to all files, especially to everyone. Instead identify the script giving you permission error and only fix that. Or at least do: `find -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;` to give execution permission only to file owner and only to files in bin dirs.

Comment: Thank You!  This worked for me....  I already did the command granting all write permission, but guess it needs execute too

Answer (score 23):

If file and/or directory permissions were changed to more restrictive ones, a permission error like the following can happen on Ubuntu Linux:

```
$ npm run watch

> watch
> mix watch

sh: 1: mix: Permission denied
```

to resolve that on Ubuntu Linux, this worked for me:

```
chmod -R u+x node_modules
```

It gives`+` you as user`u` execution`x` permission recursively `-R` to the `node_modules` directory and everything inside it.

Be careful, think about security and do **not** use the `a`, `o` nor the `g` flag instead of the `u` flag, which would give `all`, `others` or `group` execution rights. The `g` flag might be ok, if you trust all the users in the group.

As ruuter states in comments, it would be even better for security, if you find the exact file(s) that need execution permission and grant execution permission only for these files.

Comment: It's not good idea to give execution permissions to all files. Files usually should not be executable, unless its executable script. You should instead identify the script that needs to be executable and only change the permission on that file.

Comment: I show a quick solution on how to give execution permissions as restrictively as possible, for the current user only - without time consumingly identifying the script(s) that need execution permission(s), which you call for. I also explain about the security, that permissions should be restrictive. The www-data user will not be able to execute for example. 

Also, why do you write this security concern under this answer and not under habib's answer, which shows how to give all users execution rights, @ruuter?

Comment: I would not say its restrictive as possible. You could do: `find -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;` to be much more restrictive. Identifying scripts should not be time consuming. OP error was about cross-env. So just find cross-env file. Also, what if the www-data user is the owner of the files? On shared hosting, the user running web server usually is the same as the owner of all files. About habib's answer, you are right, I fixed my mistake.

Comment: Your command, @ruuter, `find -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;` would change permissions on all folders called `bin` and their contents, depending on in which folder the command is run. Folks, be careful, that could compromise your whole system. There is no 'should' in time consumingness of finding scripts - it depends on the count of scripts and in the competence of the operator. Others than OP look for help here too, for similar npm errors, even if maybe not exactly cross-env. Also the OP probably would have permission issues also with other files than cross-env.

Comment: In what way is changing permission of files in bin dirs more compromising than on all files? Just cd into node_modules or do `find node_modules -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;` if you were worried on running it in your project dir. Obviously this command was not meant to be ran in root dir or smth, but even then, bin dirs is meant for executables. Should not compromise anything.

Comment: Because there are more `bin` directories on a system, including for the system itself, than other directories, like `node_modules`. '"Just" cd into node_modules' might not be something beginners think of - good work from your part bringing that up. I would not want `www-data` to be able to execute all scripts in the system `bin` directory.

Comment: You seem to confuse things. First, the find command runs in current dir, not "on a whole system". Same as your proposed chmod. Also, my proposed command has nothing to do with www-data user. It changes file permissions, exactly as your plain chmod, not the user. The only difference between yours and my solution, is that mine only changes files in bin dirs while yours on all files. (yes, I did not include cd to node_modules or find node_modules in my first comment, sry about that)

Comment: The command runs where ever it is run by the user, preferably in `node_modules` or its parent, though. You brought up the dangers of `www-data` in your second comment, but yes, your command has nothing to do with `www-data`. Yes, you are right about the difference, as long as the user doesn't make a mistake, accidentally running your first command somewhere not `node_modules` or its parent dir, like in the root dir `/` or what ever dirs there are on shared hosting. Good that you made your command only run in `node_modules` in your third comment. Security is about layers, also handling commands

Answer (score 13):

As @savedbeau suggests, running the following fixes this problem:

---

```
npm rebuild
```

followed by

```
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 6):

**Try this.**

```sh
$ rm -rf node_modules

$ npm cache clear --force

$ npm install npm@latest -g

$ chown -R $USER ~/.npm

$ npm install
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue.
These steps helps me :

```
rm -rf node_modules/

npm install 

npm run prod
```