# Error sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied on new Kubuntu 18 os

Tags: laravel-5, npm

In laravel 5.8 app I suffer error:

```
sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied
```

on command

```
npm run watch-poll
```

That happed after I installed ubuntu 18.04 and composer/nodejs/nmp as:

```
$ uname -a
Linux serge 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ composer --version 
Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17
$ nodejs --version 
v10.16.1
$ npm --version 
6.9.0
```

I mannully removed directory node_modules and run :

```
$ npm install

> node-sass@4.12.0 install /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /home/serge/.npm/node-sass/4.12.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node

> puppeteer@1.19.0 install /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r674921 - 112.6 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s 
Chromium downloaded to /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-674921

> core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1192 packages from 569 contributors and audited 15586 packages in 32.601s
found 0 vulnerabilities
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes$ npm run watch-poll

> @ watch-poll /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> npm run watch -- --watch-poll


> @ watch /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"


> @ development /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"

sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-08-06T14_56_10_670Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-08-06T14_56_10_688Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2019-08-06T14_56_10_709Z-debug.log
```

Mentioned files :

```
2019-08-06T14_56_10_670Z-debug.log:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'development',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--watch',
1 verbose cli   '--watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~development: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
13 verbose stack Error: @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development" "--" "--watch" "--watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch" "--watch-poll"`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ development script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

2019-08-06T14_56_10_688Z-debug.log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~watch: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch" "--" "--watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch "--watch-poll"`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

2019-08-06T14_56_10_709Z-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'watch-poll' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch-poll', 'watch-poll', 'postwatch-poll' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewatch-poll: @
6 info lifecycle @~watch-poll: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~watch-poll: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
10 silly lifecycle @~watch-poll: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run watch -- --watch-poll' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~watch-poll: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~watch-poll: Failed to exec watch-poll script
13 verbose stack Error: @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "watch-poll"
18 verbose node v10.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.1.2",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.5.2",
        "mustache": "^2.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "puppeteer": "^1.19.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Googling for decision I found [sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied on laravel mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831494/sh-1-cross-env-permission-denied-on-laravel-mix) with decision :

> Ok I figure out the problem, the storage where the project is saved is
>   auto-mounted and it have no execution permission.
>
> easily in /etc/fstab file i added exec in the mount option, like this:
>
> auto,user,exec,utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw 0 0

so I modified this partition in /etc/fstab :

```
UUID=72209A012099CD0B   /mnt/Media_sda8 ntfs-3g exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133 rw 0 0
```

and restarting the OS. I have the same problem.
Has line above correct syntax?

On prior kubuntu 18.4 installation it worked ok.

How to fix it?

Comment: I also found command npm rebuild, but it did not help.

Comment: Also I found and try decsion : rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
Then run the command

npm install cross-env

npm install  But the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First following this command

```
npm rebuild
```

then this

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the following commands.

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm package-lock.json`

`npm cache clear --force`

`npm install`