# sh: 1: tailwindcss: Permission denied // error on build process Tailwindcss CLI

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, tailwind-css

I have installed nodejs version: `v18.2.0`,

and while i am trying to build my css with tailwind, and with the build command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch
```

i just get the error:

```
sh: 1: tailwindcss: Permission denied The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', 'npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch'" terminated with exit code: 126.
```

30.5.2022 **Update**:

I have now installed nodejs and npm correctly.

My Versions are:

```
jonas@jonas-ubuntu ~> node -v

v18.2.0 

jonas@jonas-ubuntu ~> npm -v

8.11.0
```

If i now try to run to run the command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch
```

It gives me this output:

```
sh: 1: tailwindcss: Permission denied
```

A look at my user permissions with: `ls -la`

```
jonas@jonas-ubuntu ~/D/G/WOWA-BAU-NEU (main)> ls -la
insgesamt 100
drwxrwxr-x  8 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 ./
drwxrwxr-x  3 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 25 22:53 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas 11701 Mai 23 21:47 build.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas     0 Mai 23 21:47 file
drwxrwxr-x  8 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 30 13:51 .git/
drwxrwxr-x 59 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 node_modules/
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 old/
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas    60 Mai 23 21:47 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas 45723 Mai 23 21:47 package-lock.json
drwxrwxr-x  5 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 30 13:51 public/
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 src/
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas   108 Mai 23 21:47 tailwind.config.js
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 .vscode/
```

they look correct to write and read.

What I didn't really  understand was:

> If these are all OK, I would recommend looking at your user permissions globally (i.e. make sure you are in the wheel group, which can be done via: usermod -a -G wheel username).

Comment: you need to check and update the permissions the current user has for node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem again after a new installation of ubuntu and for me worked now this solution:

```
npm rebuild
```

source: [sh: 1: cross-env: Permission denied on laravel mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831494/sh-1-cross-env-permission-denied-on-laravel-mix)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similiar permission problem when i was running the init command.
in my case , the soln was to :

delete `node_modules/tailwindscss`
delete all files named tailwindcss inside `node_modules/.bin/tailwindscss`

delete `tailwind.config.js` in the main folder.

and `run npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` &
`npx tailwindcss init` commands again

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your current user doesn't have enough permissions to run the build command. As generally it is bad practice to use `sudo` with `npm` or `npx` build commands.

I would recommend you look at your user permissions (for the specific directory/files in it). You can do this via an `ls -la` command in the directory, and making sure that you have a read (`r`), write (`w`), and for some of the files executable (`x`).

If these are all OK, I would recommend looking at your user permissions globally (i.e. make sure you are in the `wheel` group, which can be done via: `usermod -a -G wheel username`).

If all of these are working, try using a different shell to spawn the instance (such as ZSH or Fish), as I have found that to help in the past in general.

Depending on your installation of node, it can often come with it's own user-group, if so, make sure that your user is part of that group (via a similar command to the above one for adding a user to the 'wheel').

Otherwise, if all else fails, your best bet would be to uninstall node via

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
npm uninstall -g npx
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

...and reinstall it via

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g npx
```

Comment: I have now installed nodejs and npm correctly, but the problem is still there. I also tried a different shell (Fish) but this did not work. I think my problem is the user permission, but i dont know where. If you can see the Problem in my updated question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest things to do is double check your folder ownership and permissions. If you're on Apache for instance this will generally be `www-data`.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project/
```

You could try updating permissions also;

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/project/
```

Its worth checking the ownership of the node_modules folder as well, incase this isn't www-data for example, from /path/to/project/;

```
ls -lah
```

Answer (score 0):

1: tailwind must be called from the same directory where you installed it, possibly from the same directory where node packages and modules resides...
if you have `node_modules` installed in `/var/www/website.com/your_node_directory/node_modules` run from `your_node_directory`.

2:

```bash
$ chmod 755 tailwind.config.js && chown www-data:www-data tailwind.config.js
```

3: In the directory of your node configs assuming your tailwind.config.js file resides into there, run... `npx tailwindcss -i /your/input/file/path.css -o /your/output/file/path.css`

You do **not** need to rebuild your project -
just find out what permissions you running on..